# Revert-without-query, regex pattern error

Tags: regular-expressions

```
(setq revert-without-query '("\*"))
```

I have set this to avoid emacs' `yes/no` prompt when i revert a buffer and discard its changes. But, still the prompt keeps coming.

Other regex patterns, i tried with no success,

```
(setq revert-without-query '("*"))
(setq revert-without-query '("\\*"))
```

The doc, [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Reverting.html)says, set the variable revert-without-query to a list of regular expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regexp `"*"` is not a valid regexp, `"*"` means that whatever precedes it can occur zero or more times. A regexp that match anything can be written `".*"`, or more simply `""`.

So, you can try this:

```
(setq revert-without-query '(".*"))
```